# I'm trying to catch an exception if socket_connect is failed but it is showing something else automatically

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to catch an exception if `socket_connect` failed or timeout but it automatically displays an "internal server error"…

My code is below:

```
//function to make connection
public static function connect()
{
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); 
    //create socket
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 5, 'use' => 0));
    //set option

    try{
        //throwing exceptions here
        $result = @socket_connect($socket, 127.0.0.1,80);
        if ($result === false)
        {
            throw new customException("connect error");
        }
    }
    //cathcing exception here     
    catch(customException $e)
    {
        echo "exception occurs";
    }

    return $socket;
}
```

Comment: When you get an internal server error, check your PHP error log to see what the problem is. It's usually a syntax error in the code.

Comment: by default timeout is 30s and this code supposed to set timeout 5 sec so i can handle it before system handles it. but dont know why it is not working

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, the code isn't even running, usually because of a syntax error. The timeout is irrelevant.

Comment: try `@socket_connect` without the '@'